# valid() function is not working fine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery-validation plugin.When I click update(updte) first it works fine it display error lable for three fields.When I click delete(dlt) first it checks for the name field and then if i click update(updte) it again checks only name field and give form as valid.when it goes to the the dlt function first it takes the rules for name.Then if it goes to the updte function there also it takes rules for name and passing the the form as valid though phno and address were empty

my code:

```
var myrules ={rules :   {
        name : {
            check : true,
        },
        address : {
            check : true,
        },
        phno : {
            check : true,
        },
}

updte: function(){
        var form = this.refs.myform.getDOMNode();
        this.checkField();
        $(form).validate(myrules);
        console.log($(form).valid());
   }

dlt: function(){
        var form = this.refs.myform.getDOMNode();
        this.checkField();
        $(formNode).validate({rules :{
                            name : {
                                check : true,
                            },

                         }
                    });
        console.log($(form).valid());
   }

    checkField : function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("check",function(value,element){
        if(value){
            return true;
        }
    },"This is required");
```

Comment: and your question is? :) "Not working fine" is too broad.

Comment: when it goes to the the dlt function first it takes the rules for name.if it goes to the updte function there also it takes rules for name and pssin the the form as valid though phno and address were empty

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the `.valid()` method.  The problem lies within incorrect assumptions about the `.validate()` method.  You are calling it repeatedly within your `dlt` and `updte` functions and expecting it to do something it was not designed to do.

The `.validate()` method is **only** used for *initializing* the plugin on your form.  It is only supposed to get called **once** when the page is loaded, via DOM ready handler, and it is NOT supposed to be called multiple times.  After it's called once, all *subsequent calls are ignored*.

If you need to dynamically change the rules after initialization, the developer has provided [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) for this purpose.

1. Call `.validate()` once on DOM ready to initialize the plugin.
2. Only call `.rules('add')` and possibly `.rules('remove')` within your `dlt` and `updte` functions to setup your rules as needed.